# Getting null pointer exception in Google Map Integration

Tags: java, android

I am trying to add user current location to the map. For this purpose, I want to get latitude and longitude from location call back and want to set this latitude and longitude to the onMapReady Marker to show my current location. But in OnMapReady I found latitude longitude null.

How to solve it?

I have provided the entire code below:

```
package com.example.smarthrm;

import androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    GoogleMap mMap;
    FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
    LocationRequest locationRequest;
    LocationCallback locationCallback;
    Double latitude,longitude;
    //to show the address from lat & long
    Geocoder geocoder;
    List<Address> addresses;
    LatitudeLongitudeModel latitudeLongitudeModel;
    Double mLat,mLong;
    String address;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


        //to show the address from lat & long
        geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.ENGLISH);

        locationCallback = new LocationCallback(){

            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) { 
                super.onLocationResult(locationResult);

                if(locationResult != null)
                {
                    for(Location location : locationResult.getLocations())
                    {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();

                        latitudeLongitudeModel = new LatitudeLongitudeModel(String.valueOf(latitude),String.valueOf(longitude));

                        //to show the address from lat & long
                        try {
                            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude,longitude,1);
                            address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0)+"\n"+addresses.get(0).getLocality()+"\n"+addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
                            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, ""+address, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity
                                .this, latitude+ "  "+longitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        createLocationRequest();


    }



    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        if(latitude!= null && longitude != null)
        {
            LatLng sydney = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in "+ address));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
        }

    }


    private void createLocationRequest() 
    {

        locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);  

        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION , Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},101);

            return;
        }

        fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest,locationCallback,null);

    }

}
```

Comment: Try to debug !.....1) check the loop for locationResult.getLocations() is setting the values. 2) check you are calling the method onMapReady() with the same instance in which you set the values for latitude and longitude

Comment: First, Check for the Location permissions,Api Key ...and debug your code...

Comment: I am getting latitude and longitude from locationResults. Then I put these to the gloval variables to use them in onMapReady. But in onMapReady latitude , longitude are getting null.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for getting current location

```
 private fun getLastLocation() {
                mFusedLocationClient.lastLocation.addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                    val location: Location? = task.result
                    if (location == null) {
                        requestNewLocationData()
                    } else {
                        val mylocation = LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)
                        mMap.clear()
                        mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(mylocation).title("My Location"))
                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mylocation, 14f))
                    }
                }
    }
    private fun requestNewLocationData() {
        val mLocationRequest = LocationRequest()
        mLocationRequest.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
        mLocationRequest.interval = 0
        mLocationRequest.fastestInterval = 0
        mLocationRequest.numUpdates = 1
        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
        mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(
            mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback,
            Looper.myLooper()
        )
    }
```